# Disable cells on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 Sheets Main and Subsheet.

MainSheet has a drop down yes/no. If user selects yes, subsheet cells should be enabled and if he select no "cells should be disabled".

Also, if users select "no" and tries to click on disabled cells msg should be displayed saying "click ok to enable cells" and value in dropdown should change to "yes" on main sheet.

Below function on Main Sheet

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("G11")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case (Target.Value)
        Case "YES"
            Call Notify
        Case "NO"
            Call Notify
            Exit Sub
    End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Below function, I have used a module.

```
Public Sub Notify()
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents And Not mMessageDisplayed Then
        mMessageDisplayed = True
        If MsgBox("Cells are locked on current sheet, press ok to Unlock", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN").Range("G11") = "YES"
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Subsheet")
                .Range("E13:E14").Locked = False
            End With
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN").Range("G11") = "NO"
             With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Subsheet")
                .Range("E13:E14").Locked = True
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Below function on SubSheet

```
Private mMessageDisplayed As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Notify
End Sub
```

Functions are working. The only concern is...I get the message prompt even when the user has already selected "Yes". Intention is to get the msg prompt only if he has selected no and comes to subsheet and tries to edit it.

Comment: You are trying to call Notify, but your sub is named NotifyU...typo?

Comment: Also, in NotifyU, you are testing for mMessageDisplayed but aren't setting a value for it until after, and it isn't being passed in.

Comment: @Rdster Apologize for the typo and added the mMessageDisplayed.

Comment: Any suggestions, please

Comment: Are the functions working? Do they need to see the subsheet if they select no? If they do not need to see it, just hide it.

Comment: @Niclas Functions are working. But only concern is...I get the message prompt even when the user has already selected "Yes". Intention is to get the msg prompt only if he has selected no and comes to subsheet and tries to edit it